# Highest concentration area

Tags: r, geospatial, quadtree, spatial-index, geohashing

I try to find groups of points within a radius of 300 meters that gather the highest amount. I am looking for the coordinates of this point. Note that the center point of the area that gather the highest amount has no reason to be a point in data frame observations.

I have the following data:

```
observations <- spatialrisk::insurance %>%
  dplyr::select(amount, lon, lat)
```

The function spatialrisk::concentration determines the concentration for all target points (i.e. sub):

```
spatialrisk::concentration(sub = observations, 
                           full = observations, 
                           value = amount, radius = 300)
```

The function is written in C++ (Rcpp), and is therefore fast. However, the approach is not 'smart'.

Any ideas for a faster solution with the raster (or velox) package? Or with a kernel density approach.

Comment: Have you tried [fkde: Fast Kernel Density Estimation](https://github.com/DavidHofmeyr/fkde)?

Comment: Thanks @Majid for your answer. Much appreciated. However, wonder how the fkde package should be used to find a solution for the above problem? Any thoughts, please.

Comment: Unfortunately, not. I suggest you contact the author of the package and let's hope he will help.

Comment: Can you post some sample data so we know what you're working with?

Comment: @StewartMacdonald My data is nearly perfect comparable to data set spatialrisk::insurance.